# AcquireToken method with User Credential throwing error while trying to fetch token

Tags: c#, authentication, jwt, adal, adfs3.0

I am trying to fetch token from ADFS server with user credentials at then it is throwing this error MSIS9605: The client is not allowed to access the requested resource. I am trying to fetching token from on premisis ADFS server.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Nikolaus thank you for the suggestion. Now I can't alter the question from next time onwards i will be judicious when trying to pose a question. Here is the detailed explanation of my problem, The thing is that I am trying to fetch token from on premisis ADFS Server using AcquireToken method in AuthenticationContext Class by passing User Credentials at then i am getting this error The client is not allowed to access the requested resource.

Comment: If you opened a new question with your issue, please delete/close this one, cause it's not supposed to be this way.

Comment: How is the client registered in ADFS: as a native app or service (confidential client)? Is it granted permission to get tokens to the API? Note that only public clients (native apps) can use Resource Owner flow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a rule to permit or deny users based on an incoming claim.

In Windows Server, you can use an Access Control Policy to create a rule that will permit or deny users based on an incoming claim. Also, you can permit all users to access the relying party, use the Permit Everyone Access Control Policy or the Permit All Users rule template

You can refer to the article below for creating the rule by using the AD FS Management.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/identity/ad-fs/operations/create-a-rule-to-permit-or-deny-users-based-on-an-incoming-claim?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Or you also can use the following command with related parameters running in PowerShell.

```
Add-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust -Name "Fabrikam" -MetadataURL "https://fabrikam.com/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml" -IssuanceAuthorizationRules '=> issue(Type ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/authorization/claims/permit", value="true");'
```

Also on windows server , you need to explicitly grant clients permission to a resource, even when the access policy is set to "Permit everyone".

Try this command:

```
Grant-AdfsApplicationPermission -ClientRoleIdentifier "clientName" -ServerRoleIdentifier "https://service.url"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the help,Our problem is we are having on premisis ADFS Server we need  to fetch token from this on premisis ADFS server by passing user credentials.                                                       AuthenticationResult res = ac.AcquireToken(resourceURI, ClientID, new UserCredential("xyz@const.com","password@123"));